# Loading TensorFlow Object Detection Model After Export

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have trained an Object Detection model using the TensorFlow API by following the steps provided in [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#preparing-the-workspace) official tutorial. As such, by the end of the whole process, as described in [the exporting step](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model), I have got my model saved in the following format.

```
my_model/
├─ checkpoint/
├─ saved_model/
└─ pipeline.config
```

My question is, once the model has been saved to such a format, how can I load it and use it to make detections?

I am able to successfully do that with the training checkpoints by using the code below. And it is after that point (where I load the checkpoint that generated the best result) that I export the model.

```
# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_PIPELINE_CONFIG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(PATH_TO_CKPT).expect_partial()
```

However, in production, I am not looking to use those checkpoints. I am looking to load the model from the exported format.

I have tried the following command to load the exported model, but I have had no luck. It returns no errors and I can use the *model* variable below to make detections, but the output (bounding boxes, classes, scores) is incorrect, which leads me to believe there are some steps missing in the loading process.

```
model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_exported_model)
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as it turns out, the code is correct. I ran a test with another model (which is also an EfficientDet) and the code worked. It seems something went wrong when the original model was exported, which I am still trying to figure out.

To those looking for an answer, here's the full code for loading and using a saved model.

```
# Loading saved mode.
model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_exported_model)

# Pre-processing image.
image = tf.image.decode_image(open(path_to_image, 'rb').read(), channels=3)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
image = tf.image.resize(image, (size_expected_by_model, size_expected_by_model))

# Model expects tf.uint8 tensor, but image is read as tf.float32.
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.uint8)

# Executing object detection.
detections = model(image)

# Formatting returned detections.
num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}

detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this link.....Abdul Rehman has few python codes to run detection of saved_models to inference on Images as well as Videos......I use the codes extensively, to check on detection on saved_models from the TF2 Model Zoo, as well as trained models on custom datasets......

https://github.com/abdelrahman-gaber/tf2-object-detection-api-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what @Matheus Correia posted, I slightly modified his answer to suit what I was doing (in 2022) in google colabs.

```
category_index = your_generated_label_map
# e.g. category_index = {1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'tomato'}, 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'egg'}, 3: {'id': 3, 'name': 'potato'}, 4: {'id': 4, 'name': 'broccoli'}, 5: {'id': 5, 'name': 'beef'}, 6: {'id': 6, 'name': 'chicken'}}

# set your own threshold here
Threshold = 0.5

def ExtractBBoxes(bboxes, bclasses, bscores, im_width, im_height):
    bbox = []
    class_labels = []
    for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
        if bscores[idx] >= Threshold:
          y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
          x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
          y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
          x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)
          class_label = category_index[int(bclasses[idx])]['name']
          class_labels.append(class_label)
          bbox.append([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class_label, float(bscores[idx])])
    return (bbox, class_labels)

# @Matheus Correia's code but modified

# Loading saved mode.
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load("--saved model folder's path--")
# model = tf.saved_model.load("--saved model folder's path--")

# Pre-processing image.
image = tf.image.decode_image(open(IMAGE_PATH, 'rb').read(), channels=3)
image = tf.image.resize(image, (width,height))
im_height, im_width, _ = image.shape
# Model expects tf.uint8 tensor, but image is read as tf.float32.
input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

bboxes = detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy()
bclasses = detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.int32)
bscores = detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy()
det_boxes, class_labels = ExtractBBoxes(bboxes, bclasses, bscores, im_width, im_height)
print(class_labels)
```

Hope this helps.